# Does facebook OAuth understand localhost redirect url?

Tags: oauth, facebook-login, facebook-oauth

This is the error that I see

[image]

I have an angular2 app where my url for login are #ed usls.
This is what I configured

[image]

Comment: you should use the js sdk instead, no redirect url needed

Answer (score 0):

It has to the oauth server url. In this case firebase was providing the auth server, So I had to add to Valid OAuth redirect URIs:

`https://your-app-1234.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler`

Answer (score 0):

To use localhost in redirect URL, you need add "localhost" as "App Domains". From "Setting", click "Basic", add "localhost" in "App Domains".